# Borders Around EditFields - Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I am trying to draw a border around two text boxes, which works if I leave background colour of the main screen alone.  The client's spec's call for a colour scheme with a blue background.  When the EditFields are drawn to the screen, they appear as one field that spans the screen.  There are 2 since each gets focus when it's supposed two and everything works otherwise.  The two EditFields are then added to a GridFieldManager to control the layout.[image]

I  am subclassing the EditFields and adding the border around each of the EXEditFields, like so:

```
public class EXEditField extends EditField {

    ...


    private void init( MainScreen scrn ) {
                if ( this.hasVirtualKeyboard() )
                    this.vkbd = scrn.getVirtualKeyboard();

                this.setMaxSize( this.MAX_CHARS );

                this.setBorder( BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(0,0,0,0), Border.STYLE_SOLID) );
                this.setBackground( BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE) );
                //this.setPadding( 3, 3, 3, 3 );
                //this.setMargin( 0, 3, 0, 3 );
            }

    ...

    } // end class
```

Any help is greatly appreciated since there is not much in the way good Blackberry reference docs.

Comment: Mike it is a bit unclear what are going to achieve. Do you want border around of EACH of the two edit fields? Also do you need the border/background of the edit fields to be changed on focus on/off?

Comment: @Arhimed  My bad.  Edited for clarification.  Nothing about how the fields are displayed are altered, or are trying be altered because of a focus change, or any other change.

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear for me. Is this true: 'you are trying to display borders around EXEditField, but it does not display the borders'? Or anything else?

Comment: @Arhimed Yes. I am trying to display a border around each of the EXEditFields to visually separate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, check [this](https://github.com/cleverua/blackberry_custom_fields/blob/master/src/com/cleverua/bb/fields/CustomEditField.java).

It is an open source library that provides some custom BlackBerry fields, including an EditField, with custom borders.  You should be able to modify the code to display the borders you want.

Comment: @Arihmed I should have you on speed dial.  I think you answered every blackberry question I have out up here.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the paintBackground method within your custom EditField, try putting this code into your EditField class:

```
    protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {

        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
```